# Changing grails.serverURL has no effect on createLinkTo( [...], absolute:'true')?

Tags: java, grails, applet, config

I'm trying to display a Java applet in a page on a Grails server. I'm using Sun's handy Javascript snippet for displaying applets:

```
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
deployJava.runApplet({codeBase:"${createLinkTo(dir:'applet', absolute:'true')}",
    archive:"${createLinkTo(dir:'com/steve/applet', file='applet.jar', absolute:'true')}",
    code:"com.steve.Applet.class",
    width:"500", height:"500"}, null, "1.5");
</script>
```

In Config.groovy, I set up the different serverURLs:

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://10.0.xx.xxx/"
    }
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://10.0.yy.yyy:8080/"
    }
}
```

However, the links created by createLinkTo() all have "http://localhost:8080" instead of the URL I specified. (i.e. they look like "http://localhost:8080/my-app/applet".) Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. Instead of using createLinkTo, I just defined a new variable in Config.groovy:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.appURL = "http://10.0.xx.xxx:8080/my-app"
    }   
    production {
        grails.appURL = "http://10.0.yy.yyy"
    }
}
```

In my code, I do this:
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH

```
//...
def appURL = CH.config.grails.appURL
//...
```

This at least lets me get a predictable path.

Comment: FYI, this `g.createLinkTo` has been deprecated. You should now use  `g.resource`